# How do I get a refernce to a dialog box of another program so that I can click a button

Tags: c#, .net, automation

I have been successful in getting a reference to a running application in .net, and I have been able to use that reference to click buttons.

This is code that gets the reference and uses it.

```
string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(FindFile("BuildWellnessFile.exe", "C:\\Users\\" + name + "\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\"));
Type t = testAssembly.GetType("BuildWellnessFile.Form1");
testForm = (Form)testAssembly.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RunApp), testForm);

object[] p = { this, new EventArgs() };
InvokeMethod(testForm, "CountButton_Click", p);
```

This is supporting code

```
Assembly testAssembly = null;
Form testForm = null;

static void RunApp(object state)
{
 Application.Run((Form)state);
}

private void InvokeMethod(Form form, string methodName, params object[] parms)
{
 EventHandler eh = (EventHandler)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler),form,methodName);
  if (eh != null)
  {
   form.Invoke(eh, parms);
  }
}
```

After this the InvokeMethod is used to click the button in the other application, a dialog box pops up. I want to get a reference to that dialog box so that I can Press OK.

Please don't mention best practices about automating another application, I'm just asked to get things done.

UPDATE:
Here is how the other application calls the dialog box

```
Interaction.MsgBox(" active cards in list created at: ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, Nothing)
```

Comment: Is it modal? You can just emulate space bar push down event.

Comment: The computer it will be running on, will not guarantee the focus on the dialog box. I need to figure out how to get a reference to the dialog.

Comment: So you are not interested in using Window UI Automation, which is the normal way to programmatically interact with other applications (used primarily for accessibility support)?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use P/Invoke to send BM_CLICK message to appropriate button in dialog box. Some example how to do this in C# is at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsAPIsFromCS.aspx